How to add extensions to webdriver Chrome in changedetection.io?
I started to self host changedetection.io to monitor a website for new listings. The problem is that I absolutely need an extension to display further informations that I will eventually fetch. I installed it on the server using the instructions for docker that can be found on their github.
Changedetection proposes multiple ways to fetch content from a webpage but I only really use the webdriver based one.
Now, if I understood correctly, to add an extension, you need to add the .crx file of the extension in the options of webdriver :
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_extension('extensionname.crx')

driver = (webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

I think it's probably clear that I'm a complete newbie and don't really understand a lot of what I'm doing. What I need to know is where to add the said option in changedetection.io. Is it in docker-compose.yml? Is it in one of the dozens of .py files? I don't know
Thank you very much!!
